# Using buffers in the QGIS field calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, buffer

This is my first time using QGIS and I am using the field calculator.

I've created a map with a bunch of points representing trees (and their species) and shapes representing parks in my city. I've also got a geocoded layer containing some survey responses.

Basically, I'm looking to add new fields in my survey dataset with the following information, to then export and do further statistical analysis on:

- The total number of trees within various buffer distances (100m,
  500m, 1000m)
- The number of different species within these buffer
  distances if possible
- The number of parks (and other shape data)
  within the buffer distances

Am also trying to figure out ways to do this with 'count points in polygon' and some other tools but the field calculator seems like the way to go?

Attached a pic of a tiny bit of my map for reference.

[image]

Comment: Please provide details on what you tried and researched and where exactly you're stuck.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Erik at the moment what I'm doing is a very laborious process. I've created my buffers around each of the questionnaire data points. Then, using the 'Count points in polygon tool' I can see how many of each type of tree and count the number of different species within each buffer. Each of these bits of information, however, is in a new csv file which I'll then have to go through and add to my main dataset. I was hoping to be able to automate this!